# Client-server TypeScript app - which server kind?

Tags: c#, web-applications, web, client-server, typescript

I would like to start making a `JS` application that works with `C#-based` server. It will be a small website with some features that should be performed at the server-side (database + basic account authentication needed).

I wanted to use `HTML5` + `TypeScript` to create a client.

I have some questions:

1. What is the best idea to make a server?
2. What kind of client-server communication should I choose?
3. What about hosting? Should I use `Windows Azure` or anything different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best idea to make a server?

Really broad question. No best. Advice : Using something that is *API* focused. If you want to keep it all in TypeScript (to decrease cognitive overload) you can use Node.js + Express http://expressjs.com/

> What kind of client-server communication should I choose?

You have two broad categories. Server side rendering (where you modify the HTML returned from the server before it reaches the client) and Client side rendering (where you modify the HTML based on some client JavaScript, example with angular : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1). You will most likely use a combination of both.

> What about hosting? Should I use Windows Azure or anything different?

Again really broad. Depends a bit on your server side tech. Both Azure and Amazon (EC2) are good first choices and basically provide you a hosted virtual machine in the cloud on which you can put *whatever* you want.